# Change script run from commandline to django view

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views

I have a script that i run from command to populate a django model from csv..
the command i use is:

```
python artifact_db_loader.py -tzusb "d:\Test_Data\david nides\david-nides-usb.csv" -e 44
```

I want to change this so that it can be run on a django view on page request.
Anyone with an insight please?
Regards,
Josh

Comment: simple . `artifact_db_loader.py` add this file to project root dir . make new function that accepts your `arguments` . call it from django view .

Comment: Priyank Please give more guidelines on this..I can give you more details

Comment: Django has a whole section in their documentation explaining how to do it. Did you read the doc?

Comment: point me to the doc you referring to Bibhas

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided any details about the script, I'm assuming there is a function inside that takes the filename and a model name as parameters and does the work when invoked from the terminal. You can simply move that function to a controller and call it with both the parameters on request.

Django has a [whole section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code) in their documentation explaining how to do it.

Comment: the link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you can do anything you would do on a regular python script inside a Django view. For example :

```
#! python3
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*

from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
import os

def myView(request):
    f = open('file.cvs', 'w')
    f.write('Whatever you want')
    f.close()
return HttpResponse('Done.')
```

You can put conditions and loops, so you should be able to put your entire script as a view like that.